# Devise edit/update profile won't do PATCH or PUT - I always get GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added Devise to my rails app and everything works fine, except when I try to change a profile - I can seem to make the form do a PUT or PATCH.

This is my setup

My edit.html.haml:

```
    = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :patch }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  .form-group
    %label.col-sm-2.control-label{:for => "inputName"} Name
    .col-sm-10
      = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Name", class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    %label.col-sm-2.control-label{:for => "inputEmail"} Email
    .col-sm-10
      = f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Name", type: "email", class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :password, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", type: "password", class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :password_confirmation, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Retype password", :type => "password", class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
    .col-sm-10
      = f.file_field :avatar



  .form-group
    .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
      %button.btn.btn-danger{:type => "submit"} Submit
```

My routes.rb file...I only have that one line concerning devise - at the very top.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
```

rake routes:

```
                        Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                                 Controller#Action
          new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                    devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                    devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                   devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                                                   devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                                               devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                                              devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                                   devise/passwords#update
                           PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                                   devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                                                            devise/registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                    devise/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                                       devise/registrations#edit
                           PATCH    /users(.:format)                                                            devise/registrations#update
                           PUT      /users(.:format)                                                            devise/registrations#update
                           DELETE   /users(.:format)                                                            devise/registrations#destroy
```

When ever i try to change a profile via the form I get an GET request even though the method is set to PUT. I have tried with PATCH as well.

EDIT
I don't understand that the url for the form is:

```
registration_path(resource_name)
```

That isn't even listed when I do a rake routes. I don't get any errors, tho

Comment: is jquery working properly?

Comment: It is... but devise does not use jquery...does it? this seems to be a standard rails request

Comment: The url `registration_path(resource_name)` simply says that for the model that you created using command `rails generate devise User` translates to the route definitions you posted above. Here **resource_name** = **User**, the model name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me - I had a misplaced form tag that made the GET request before getting the the PUT form tag

Comment: I am having similar problem, what was the issue with the form tag?
can you share some code?